# ASP.NET MVC : calling a controller from another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am writing a web application with `ASP.NET MVC`, and I would like to call a controller from another controller. More precisely I would like to call a routine in the Login controller, where I do sign in and sign out, from the controller where I allow the normal user to change his/her password. Thus, I check the old password (given by the user in the change password form).

I tried to search in the internet methods to change user (not Administrator) password but I didn't find anything good.

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you expect to call the same view as the other controller, I suggest you pull that logic out of the controller and into a method. Then, both controller can just call that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn´t called a controller from another controller, instead I called my User Administration Controller `AdminController` from a View within the `HomeController` controller (via na `input` button).

Then the code of my routine `EditByUser` in the `AdminController` was written as:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditByUser(string email, string passwordnew, string passwordconf)
        {
            AppUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            if (user != null)
            {
                IdentityResult validEmail
                    = await userValidator.ValidateAsync(userManager, user);
                if (!validEmail.Succeeded)
                {
                    AddErrorsFromResult(validEmail);
                }                

                IdentityResult validPassnew = null;
                bool passNewEqPassConf = passwordconf == passwordnew;
                if (!passNewEqPassConf)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "New Password not equal to Confirmation!");
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordnew) && passNewEqPassConf)
                {
                    validPassnew
                        = await passwordValidator.ValidateAsync(userManager, user, passwordnew);
                    if (validPassnew.Succeeded)
                    {
                        user.PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, passwordnew);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrorsFromResult(validPassnew);
                    }
                }
                if (((validEmail.Succeeded && validPassnew == null)
                    || (validEmail.Succeeded
                        && passwordnew != string.Empty && validPassnew.Succeeded)) && passNewEqPassConf)
                {
                    IdentityResult result = await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { email = user.Email });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrorsFromResult(result);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "User not found!");
            }

            return View(user);
        }
```

However, I didn't manage to check the old password… The sign in is made on another controller…